# Order by SUM, but do NOT aggregate the result set (order by subtotals)

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, h2

I've got the following table

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| STORE  | PRODUCT  | AMOUNT |
+--------+----------+--------+
| store1 | product1 |    100 |
| store1 | product2 |     90 |
| store2 | product2 |     95 |
| store2 | product1 |     90 |
| store3 | product1 |    120 |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

The thing is, I want to order this table by the sum of amount of every store. In this example, store1 has 190, store2 has 185 and store3 120. So the ordering is granted on this example, and I also want to order by amount of each product, but don't want to get this outside the scope of "store", and don't want to group by because I need to show all the rows...

How can I achieve this ordering in H2 database? I can appreciate other databases, but H2 is my main concern.

Btw, performance is a big issue here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most databases, you would use a window function.  H2 doesn't support them.  So you need to do an explicit join:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select store, sum(amount) as totalamount
      from table t
      group by store
     ) ts
     on t.store = ts.store
order by ts.totalamount desc, ts.store;
```

Notice that `store` is in the `order by`.  This handles the case where two scores have the same total.  All rows for each store will still be together.

Comment: is this the best way to deal with this? I wanted to avoid joins, because performance is a big issue

Comment: I think your only options are an explicit join (as in the answer) or an implicit join using a correlated subquery.